# HBase Error : zookeeper.znode.parent mismatch

Tags: hadoop, hbase

i am trying to learn Hadoop and i'v reached HBase section in Hadoop Definitive Guide.
i tried to start HBase and got error. Could someone give me step-by-step guide?

```
opel@ubuntu:~$ zkServer.sh start
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/opel/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
opel@ubuntu:~$ start-hbase.sh 
starting master, logging to /home/opel/hbase-0.94.20/logs/hbase-opel-master-ubuntu.out
opel@ubuntu:~$ hbase shell
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.94.20, r09c60d770f2869ca315910ba0f9a5ee9797b1edc, Fri May 23 22:00:41 PDT 2014

hbase(main):001:0> status
14/06/02 22:40:44 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/06/02 22:40:45 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/06/02 22:40:47 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/06/02 22:40:49 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/06/02 22:40:51 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/06/02 22:40:55 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/06/02 22:40:59 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times

Here is some help for this command:
Show cluster status. Can be 'summary', 'simple', or 'detailed'. The
default is 'summary'. Examples:

  hbase> status
  hbase> status 'simple'
  hbase> status 'summary'
  hbase> status 'detailed'
```

is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. For me the solution was to add the following property to the `hbase-site.xml` (for me it can be found under `/usr/lib/hbase/conf` directory):

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
                <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

But this is only for the standalone mode. I still have no idea how to solve this problem when using external ZooKeeper.

Comment: can you explain what it does? i mean the hbase-unsecure and znode thing?

Comment: @spyro I'm running Hbase using the Cloudera VM image on Virtual Box (test setup). Above didn't work. Can you tell us what else could be the issue?

Comment: @spyro - if you look through the zookeeper znodes the /hbase-unsecure is the name of the znode where all the hbase info is being kept per this installation.

Comment: @Cleankod /hbase-unsecure is the default ZooKeeper parent node created by Ambari if you are working with HDP. The default Zookeeper parent node is /hbase

Answer (score 3):

there wont be any problem with the configurations if you are using the Cloudera Manager VM.

The problem is HMaster is not up. To resolve it, go to Cloudera Manager and restart the HBase services. it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem I could able to fix this by not using zookeeper. 
If you're running HBase in standalone mode then you don't need zookeeper. I could able to skip the zookeeper part my making the *hbase.cluster.distributed* property *false*.

`<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>`

Now, I could able to play with hbase without zookeeper.

Answer (score 0):

In cloudera management page, Goto services -> hbase1 and start the sevice problem will be resolved. No need to make the hbase unsecure property.

Answer (score 0):

This problem tooks me a whole night, and this is how i resolved it:
After starting hadoop, go to : `http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-datanode`

You will see a list of available datanode in a table, you just need to add it in your `hbase-site.xml` as follow for me:

```xml
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
                <value>127.0.0.1:50010</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing check your HBase logs. It will give you the clear idea about the error. In my case i was running Kafka + zookeeper and HBase on the same server. So, whenever i was trying to run hbase shell i was kept getting same error on the console. When I checked logs and found

> port is already in use

so i just changed the value for

> hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort

in hbase-site.xml file and everything start running.

Answer (score 0):

open zookeeper/bin and run the command - **./zkServer.sh start**

After successful execution, execute command - **/zkCli.sh**

then execute command **get /hbase-unsecure**

if it returns as null then, **create -s /testmaster "127.0.0.1:2222"**

Also, edit hbase-site.xml by adding

```
   <property>
            <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
            <value>/testmaster</value>
    </property>
```

PS - keep the value of hbase.cluster.distributed property as false.

Hope this solves your error.