# exception like Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I'm using hbase0.94.3, hadoop-2.2.0 and jdk 1.7.71 version. Everything was working fine. Now, all of a sudden HBase is failing to start.

At first I got error:

```
ERROR zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries
14/10/17 20:27:44 WARN zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection Unable to set watcher on znode /hbase/master
```

Then I started the zookeeper service (in bin of hbase hbase-daemon `start zookeeper`) and re-installed the operating system itself.

Then started getting

```
14/10/17 20:35:38 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplem  Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
```

In HBase shell after running command `list`, I get the above mentioned error.

In the net I found one solution 
[HBase Error : zookeeper.znode.parent mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008207/hbase-error-zookeeper-znode-parent-mismatch)

```
<property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
    <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
</property>
```

I added the above mentioned configuration in hbase-site.xml. I am still facing the same error. Kindly help me to resolve the issue.