# What is 'zookeeper.znode.parent'?

Tags: debian, apache-zookeeper, nutch

I'm currently trying to run a Nutch job under Hadoop on a single-node cluster (just the master, no slaves).

I run the following:

```
hadoop jar /var/www/html/nutch/nutch4/build/apache-nutch-2.3.job org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob urls
```

But, every time I execute this, I get the following error:

> ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.

The problem is when I google 'zookeeper.znode.parent' I get essentially no useful results.

I know sort of the purpose of zookeeper and I'm learning Hadoop but I'm still a novice.

What does this error mean? How can I fix it so I may run my Nutch job?

Edit: I'm not working with HBase and its managed zookeeper instance. I'm trying to use Hadoop and discover what 'zookeeper.znode.parent' is and what it's for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24008207/1531971

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this does not apply to me. That is for HBase and its internal zookeeper instance. I'm running an external instance of zookeeper with Hadoop, not HBase. And unfortunately though that post may offer a solution to OP's question, it doesn't explain at all what zookeeper.znode.parent actually is or what it's for.

Comment: Consider this a hint that you should tell us this information in the text of the question. Otherwise, how would we know? [Edit] the question and be clear about what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get. Show what research you have done so people who want to answer don't waste their time and yours with things you have already tried. See [ask] for how to make a good question.

Comment: looks like Nutch is trying to connect to HBase, by any chance is there any integration in nutch for HBase?

Comment: @mbaxi Yes, Nutch uses HBase by default. Are you saying I need to suppress HBase somehow and that might fix my problem?

Comment: @AnthonyFrizalone I haven't worked with Nutch but my best guess would be if you add hbase-site.xml to Nutch classpath it should help, if there is a way to disable integration with HBase you can try that as well