# HBase - Jmeter Load test gives - check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'

Tags: jmeter, hbase, apache-zookeeper, jmeter-plugins

I am try to load test HBase using Jmeter.
In the Jmeter.log file I am seeing that the hbase-site.xml file is getting picked. Following is the log snippet:

```
2021-02-10 10:27:05,791 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: user.properties
2021-02-10 10:27:05,791 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: system.properties
2021-02-10 10:27:05,792 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting System property: javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false
2021-02-10 10:27:05,792 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting System property: java.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf
2021-02-10 10:27:05,792 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting System property: java.security.auth.login.config=/home/svctranhist/gss-jaas.conf
2021-02-10 10:27:05,792 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting System properties from file: /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml
2021-02-10 10:27:05,804 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2021 The Apache Software Foundation
2021-02-10 10:27:05,805 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 5.4.1
```

And hbase-site.xml has zookeeper.znode.parent property. But on running the jmx file I am getting the following error.

```
2021-02-10 09:16:08,969 ERROR o.a.h.h.z.ZooKeeperNodeTracker: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
```

I am using the following command to run the JMX file:

```
./jmeter -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/svctranhist/gss-jaas.conf -S /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml -n -t ../HBase_Load_Test_Plan.jmx -l ./hbase_50.csv
```

Am I missing something? Do I need to explicitly give zookeeper.znode.parent? I am stuck on this. Can someone please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to make sure that `zookeeper.znode.parent` in your copy of hbase-site.xml is correct. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008207/hbase-error-zookeeper-znode-parent-mismatch or HBase doc.

Comment: @mazaneicha I checked. It's correct